# Can this limit be solved with Riemann sum?

Tags: calculus, limits

> Can this limit be solved with Riemann sum?
>   $$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left[\lim _{x\to 0}\left(\cos x\cdot\cos2x\cdots\cos nx\right)^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}}\right] $$

What I've tried is to solve it with the Riemann sum but I am getting stuck somewhere , and I am not seeing where .
In my textbook I have the following options as answers :

$a. e^3$

$b. e^{-2}$

$c. e^{\frac{1}{3}}$

$d. e^{\frac{1}{2}}$

$ e. e^{\frac{-1}{6}}$

Comment: The limit as $x\to0$ doesn't exist for any $n$, as you simply get $1/0$.

Comment: @Daniel Schepler: maybe, but since then the inner limit is $\frac{1+4+\ldots+n^2}{2n^3} \sim \frac{1}{12}$, this doesn’t match the proposed answers...

Comment: Or instead of guessing what the question is, we can simply wait for the OP to clarify?

Comment: I am so sorry , i just looked , it is with an exponent , i am going to edit the question right now..

Comment: I thought i added the exponent when i've started the question, as it seems like i didn't wrote it correctly .

Comment: Can you solve $\lim\limits_{x\to0}[\cos(x)]^{1/x^2}$? (Hint: Take the log of this)

Comment: Yes , the example that you gave is with the case 0^(inf) , so if we are to wrote it as lim e^(1/x^2*ln(cos(x)) , we get 1/e^1/2.

Comment: Now, the question is how the i solve the entire limit .

Comment: Please can you share from which book is this problem taken?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x...\cos nx)^{\frac{1}{n^3x^2}}$$
As per @marty cohen, let us  use $-y+y^2/2 \le \ln(1-y)\le -y~$  and  $(1-t^2/2) \le \cos t \le (1-t^2/2+t^4/24)~$  when $~t~$ and $~y~$ are very small. We get
 $$\ln L =\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{n^3 x^2} \sum_{r=1}^{n} (\ln \cos rx)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow}\frac{1}{n^3 x^2}  \sum_{r=1}^n \ln(1-r^2x^2/2).$$ $$\Rightarrow \ln L = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \lim_{x\rightarrow} \frac{1}{n^3 x^2} \sum_{r=1}^n (-r^2x^2/2)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{r=1}^n -r^2/(2n^2)=
\int_{0}^{1}(-z^2/2) dz=\frac{-1}{6}.$$ So $L=e^{-1/6}.$

Comment: Thank you for your help ! Now, shouldn't the answer be e^-1/6 ? ( because i've posted the answers that i have in my textbook, and there's none like this)

Comment: Ok,  i seen now . Thank you !

Comment: If you like the answer, you should accept it.

Comment: To prove this rigorously, you need $1-x^2/2 \le \cos(x) \le 1-x^2/2+x^4/4$ and, for small enough $x$,  $-x-x^2 \le \ln(1-x) \le -x$.

Comment: Could you help me out with a more detalied answer,please ? ( i would like to fully understand)

Comment: @Jon9 I have made it clearer now by including marty cohen's suggestion.